# migrating 1.1 struts and struts-el to 1.2.9 in websphere

Tags: struts, websphere, struts-1, websphere-8, ibm-rad

I've been trying to migrate my web app from WASD 5.1 to RAD 8.5.1
I'm also using struts-el 1.1 and trying to upgrade to 1.2.9
I'm using websphere 8.5 
Web Dynamic 3.0 and got stuck with this error:

> /jsp/sa/SA_Login.jsp(62,1) --> JSPG0123E: Unable to locate tag attribute info for tag attribute name.
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ValidateVisitor.validateCustomTagAttributeValues(ValidateVisitor.java:1395)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.validator.ValidateVisitor.visitCustomTagStart(ValidateVisitor.java:294)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processJspElement(JspVisitor.java:366)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processChildren(JspVisitor.java:419)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.processJspElement(JspVisitor.java:234)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.visitor.JspVisitor.visit(JspVisitor.java:216)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.JspTranslator.processVisitors(JspTranslator.java:127)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.utils.JspTranslatorUtil.translateJsp(JspTranslatorUtil.java:254)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.translator.utils.JspTranslatorUtil.translateJspAndCompile(JspTranslatorUtil.java:121)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:548)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper._checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:465)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:294)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.findWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:498)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.getServletWrapper(AbstractJSPExtensionProcessor.java:338)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:965)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.dispatch(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:1384)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:193)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.doForward(RequestProcessor.java:1085)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processForwardConfig(RequestProcessor.java:398)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:241)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1224)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:774)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:456)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:97)
>     at com.SecurityServlet.doFilter(SecurityServlet.java:75)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>     at
>   com.SAReqLoggerServlet.doFilter(SAReqLoggerServlet.java:62)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:91)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:928)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1025)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3748)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:304)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:962)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1662)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:459)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:526)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:312)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:283)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1048)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:642)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1814)

My SA_Login page has this code:

```
<%@ include file = "../common/header.inc"%>
<html-el:javascript formName="SALoginFormBean" staticJavascript="false" dynamicJavascript="true" page="0" />
<script language="JavaScript1.2" src="../../js/xx.js"></script>
... to line 61 ...
<html-el:form  action="/SALogin.do" 
    name="SALoginFormBean"
    type="com.SALoginFormBean" 
    method="post"
    >
```

My header.inc is :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<%@ taglib uri="../../WEB-INF/struts-html-el.tld" prefix="html-el" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt" %>
<%@ taglib uri="../../WEB-INF/struts-bean.tld" prefix="bean" %>
<%@ taglib uri="../../WEB-INF/struts-logic-el.tld" prefix="logic-el" %>
<%@ page import ="com.*" buffer="16kb" errorPage="../errorpages/xyz.jsp"  %>
```

my struts-config is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts-config PUBLIC "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 1.2//EN"
                               "struts-config_1_2.dtd">

<struts-config>

    <!-- Data Sources -->
    <data-sources>
    </data-sources>

    <form-beans>
        <form-bean name="SALoginFormBean" type="com.tis.web.sa.SALoginFormBean"></form-bean>
```

Not sure what i'm doing wrong..
Any help would really be appreciated
If more details needed please tell me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on this link
http://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsUpgradeNotes11to124

it seems that you need to remove the name and type attribute of the html-el:form.